# Debugging a MySQL procedure in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a really basic question that I've been unable to find the answer to so far. I've read several answers but they don't seem to be working for me.

I'm not looking for someone to debug this (unless you are feeling super helpful!) I just would like some help to debug it myself.

I have the following procedure that I'm in the process of writing. I've obviously made a mistake but can someone show me the best way to debug this. When I call this procedure in phpMyAdmin I can't see what the value of `@sql` is.

I tried entering `SELECT @sql;` but that didn't seem to work as nothing was displayed when I called the procedure.

How can I find out what the value of `@sql` is so that I can properly debug this.

Thanks in advance.

```
BEGIN

    set @sql = (select concat('SELECT a.id as "Asset ID", ',
            group_concat(
                concat('max(case when ap.property_id = ',ap_id, ' then ap.', ap_data_type, '_value else null end) as "', ap_name,'",')
            )
            ,' FROM chekrite_prod.equipment AS a JOIN chekrite_prod.asset_properties ap on ap.asset_id = a.id group by a.site_id, a.asset_id;'
            )
    from 
    (
        SELECT i.id as ap_id, item as ap_name, asset_property_data_type as ap_data_type
        FROM chekrite_prod.config_items as i
        JOIN chekrite_prod.config_tables as t on t.id = i.table_id
        WHERE t.company_id = 161 AND t.class = 'asset_property'    ) a
    )
    ;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: `SELECT @sql;` should work. But `group_concat()` will separate the values with `,` by default. And you add one more `,` at the end of every pivot column. So you will get something like `max(...) as "ap_name1",,max(...) as "ap_name2",, ... max(...) as "ap_nameN", FROM`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Solved that problem but now have another. Where should I put the `SELECT @sql` so that it will display on the screen in phpMyAdmin when I call this procedure?

Comment: Replace the last three lines of the SP with `SELECT @sql;`. If it doesn't work it should at least show an error.

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately, that didn't work and no error either. Just shows the statement again.

Comment: Instead of debugging the procedure, try just the SQL statement directly in phpAdmin to see if it works. Once it's working, then put it into the procedure.

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately I can't do that as it's a dynamic statement that's pulling in information and generating it. The idea is if I can see what is in that, I can actually run the statement separately and make sure it's working then adjust the generation code.